# How to get dataset information of a HDF5 file

Tags: c++, file-io, interface, hdf5

I need access in `C++` on a generic basis to datasets stored in H5 format. Currently it is like this:

```
H5File* file = new H5File( path_to_dataset.c_str(), H5F_ACC_RDONLY );
DataSet* h5_dataset_file = new DataSet (file->openDataSet( "Dataset_name" ));
CompType dataset_access( sizeof(dataset_struct));

//...

dataset_access.insertMember(attribute_name,cur_byte_addr,PredType::NATIVE_INT32);
```

This is working, if I know all the parameters, currently I'm lacking `attribute_name` (e.g. "Feature A").

Is there a way to get all the column names in a H5 file? Or am I required to hard code it or at least utilize the user input ?

**Edit:**

I.e. for this example I need *label_id, Feature1, Feature2, Feature3*, but these names are different with every dataset:

**[image: Dataset Attributes]**:

Comment: I think you can get that information using H5Literate, H5Lvisit and H5Ovisit. Have you tried the examples from the hdf5 site? https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/discover.html

Comment: server is not responding or I don't have access

Comment: You can check the api document if you can't access the site.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the C++ HDF5 library is here:
[HDF5 C++ API](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/index.html). These give you a nice class overview aswell as some C++ examples. For some lower level stuff like attr_operator_t used in `dataset.iterate_attrs(...)`, see [HDF5 C/FORTRAN API](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5Front.html#LowLevelAPIs).

As a minimal working example, this below should work. Mind you, using a lambda instead of the `void attr_op(...)` function is probably better.

```
#include <H5Cpp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void attr_op(H5::H5Location &loc, const std::string attr_name,
             void *operator_data) {
  std::cout << attr_name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  // these are defined somewhere
  std::string file_name, dataset_name;


  H5::H5File file{file_name, H5F_ACC_RDONLY};
  auto dataset = file.openDataSet(dataset_name);

  dataset.iterateAttrs(attr_op);
}
```

from here on use the API function like the ones [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_h5_object.html).

Comment: I had to cast `attr_op` in the method call as:

`dataset.iterateAttrs((H5::attr_operator_t) attr_op);`